# Can't Open a .csproj file in the Visual Studio Designer, instead the .csproj file opens in the file editor

Tags: visual-studio

I am running Visual Studio 2022 17.8.3. I have a couple of WPF Solutions where I cannot open the .csproj file in the designer! When I click on the project in the Solution Explore then right click and select properties, it opens the file in the file editor, not the Designer!

However, I have other solutions where the .csproj opens in the Designer when I use the above technique. So, I suspect it's something about the project not the VS.

I can't find a setting in Options.

I've rebooted, restarted VS...the usual stuff

Any help would be appreciated